# Process to find nth term of a sequence with a negative indice of n?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I can find the nth term of any quadratic sequence by finding a (e.g.) second difference (Example 1 below). My question is how to find the nth term for a sequence that has (e.g.) n to the -1 or n to the -2 in its nth term (that is unknown at first)(example 2).
I have tried to use google but found irrelevant results.

Example 1

3, 9, 19, 33

\ /  \ /  \ /

6  10  14

```
\/    \/

4     4
```

4=2a
a=2
So 2n squared is used.
Take away 2n squared etc.
...
End up with 2n squared + 1.

Example 2

1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4 etc

I know the nth term is 1/n but what's the 'official' process?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "official" process. There is no single approach that can give you the expression for the $n$th term of sequences. There is just a long list of techniques which work some times, and when they don't you start guessing.